# Is it possible to use an array of arrays in WebGPU?

Tags: javascript, webgpu

How to create a buffer from an array of arrays in JavaScript and use it in a compute shader?
For example: `const arr = [new Float32Array([1, 3, 5]), new Float32Array([2, 4, 6]), ...]`
How to create a buffer for arr and declare it in the compute shader?

The intention is to create both an input and an output in the same format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For WGSL you declare an array of arrays like this

```
array<array<type, count1>, count2>
```

For example

```
array<array<vec4f, 3> 2>
```

Is an array of 2 arrays of 3 vec4fs

Back in JavaScript, how you read/write those is up to you,

As one large array

```
await buffer.mapAsync(...);
const ab = buffer.getMappedRange();  // get the entire buffer

const allData  =  new Float32Array(ab); // so 2 * 3 * 4 float32s
```

Or arrays of typed arrays,

```
const floatsPerRow = 3 * 4;            // 3 vec4fs
const bytesPerRow = floatsPerRow * 4;

const data = [
   new Float32Array(ab, bytesPerRow * 0, floatsPerRow);
   new Float32Array(ab, bytesPerRow * 1, floatsPerRow);
];
```

Or arrays of arrays of arrays

```
const floatsPerRow = 3 * 4;            // 3 vec4fs
const bytesPerRow = floatsPerRow * 4;
const bytesPerVec4f = 16;

const data = [
  [
    new Float32Array(ab, bytesPerRow * 0 + bytesPerVec4f * 0, 4),
    new Float32Array(ab, bytesPerRow * 0 + bytesPerVec4f * 1, 4),
    new Float32Array(ab, bytesPerRow * 0 + bytesPerVec4f * 2, 4),
  ],
  [
    new Float32Array(ab, bytesPerRow * 1 + bytesPerVec4f * 0, 4),
    new Float32Array(ab, bytesPerRow * 1 + bytesPerVec4f * 1, 4),
    new Float32Array(ab, bytesPerRow * 1 + bytesPerVec4f * 2, 4),
  ],
];
```

Of those, the first, just one `Float32Array` would arguably be the most common since making lots of views has a cost.

As for uploading, you could either make typed arrays that view the same buffer (like above) and then upload the entire buffer. Or you can upload one smaller typed array at a time

For example

```js
// WebGPU Simple Compute Shader
// from https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/webgpu-simple-compute.html


async function main() {
  const adapter = await navigator.gpu?.requestAdapter();
  const device = await adapter?.requestDevice();
  if (!device) {
    fail('need a browser that supports WebGPU');
    return;
  }

  const module = device.createShaderModule({
    label: 'doubling compute module',
    code: `
      @group(0) @binding(0) var<storage, read_write> data: array<array<f32, 3>>;

      @compute @workgroup_size(1) fn computeSomething(
        @builtin(global_invocation_id) id: vec3<u32>
      ) {
        let col = id.x;
        let row = id.y;
        
        data[row][col] = data[row][col] * 2.0;
      }
    `,
  });

  const pipeline = device.createComputePipeline({
    label: 'doubling compute pipeline',
    layout: 'auto',
    compute: {
      module,
      entryPoint: 'computeSomething',
    },
  });

  const input = [
    new Float32Array([
      11, 12, 13,
    ]),
    new Float32Array([
      31, 32, 33,
    ]),
  ];

  // create a buffer on the GPU to hold our computation
  // input and output
  const workBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    label: 'work buffer',
    size: input[0].byteLength * input.length,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.STORAGE | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_SRC | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST,
  });
  // Copy our input data to that buffer
  const bytesPerRow = 3 * 4
  device.queue.writeBuffer(workBuffer, bytesPerRow * 0, input[0]);
  device.queue.writeBuffer(workBuffer, bytesPerRow * 1, input[1]);

  // create a buffer on the GPU to get a copy of the results
  const resultBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    label: 'result buffer',
    size: workBuffer.size,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.MAP_READ | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST,
  });

  // Setup a bindGroup to tell the shader which
  // buffer to use for the computation
  const bindGroup = device.createBindGroup({
    label: 'bindGroup for work buffer',
    layout: pipeline.getBindGroupLayout(0),
    entries: [
      { binding: 0, resource: { buffer: workBuffer } },
    ],
  });

  // Encode commands to do the computation
  const encoder = device.createCommandEncoder({
    label: 'doubling encoder',
  });
  const pass = encoder.beginComputePass({
    label: 'doubling compute pass',
  });
  pass.setPipeline(pipeline);
  pass.setBindGroup(0, bindGroup);
  pass.dispatchWorkgroups(input[0].length, input.length);
  pass.end();

  // Encode a command to copy the results to a mappable buffer.
  encoder.copyBufferToBuffer(workBuffer, 0, resultBuffer, 0, resultBuffer.size);

  // Finish encoding and submit the commands
  const commandBuffer = encoder.finish();
  device.queue.submit([commandBuffer]);

  // Read the results
  await resultBuffer.mapAsync(GPUMapMode.READ);
  const ab = resultBuffer.getMappedRange()
  const result = [
    new Float32Array(ab, bytesPerRow * 0, input[0].length),
    new Float32Array(ab, bytesPerRow * 1, input[0].length),
  ];
  console.log('input', input);
  console.log('result', result);

  resultBuffer.unmap();
}

function fail(msg) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
  alert(msg);
}

main();
```

```css
@import url(https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/resources/webgpu-lesson.css);
```

In the example above the array is declared as

```
@group(0) @binding(0) var<storage, read_write> data: array<array<f32, 3>>;
```

Leaving off the length of the outer array means the size of the outer array is decided by the size of the buffer you bind at runtime.

You might find [this article about memory layout](https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/lessons/webgpu-memory-layout.html) and [this wsgl offset computer](https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/lessons/resources/wgsl-offset-computer.html) helpful